# How do you set the add guake to the list of alternative terminals on Kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, guake

I've recently installed Kubuntu 22.04 and am trying to set guake as the default terminal emulator. I can't seem to find any instructions on how to do it with KDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can set guake as an alternative terminal in Kubuntu 22.04 by wrapping it with a custom command:

1. Open settings to default applications

[image: default applications settings]

2. Click on "Other"

[image: terminal emulator alternatives dropdown]

3. Enter `/bin/bash -c 'guake --show --new-tab "$PWD"'` and press "Ok"

[image: /bin/bash -c 'guake --show --new-tab "$PWD"' forcibly entered in the picker`]

4. Click apply

[image: apply after press]

5. Close all application windows or reboot
6. Try opening terminal in some app

[image: dolphin open terminal context menu]

7. Guake will open to the current directory

[image: guake overlaying the desktop]